# AWS amazon SES stopped working suddenly

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-web-services

I am not able to send the mail from aws.amazon SES since from Monday (30-10-2012) previously it is working fine suddenly it stopped working. I got following is the errors

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: User Warning

Message: SimpleEmailService::getSendQuota(): Sender - RequestExpired: Request timestamp: Wed, 31 Oct 2012 11:50:32 UTC expired. It must be within 300 secs/ of server time. Request Id: e472fb5a-2351-11e2-8183-8138c6c456cf

Filename: libraries/ses.php

Line Number: 363
```

But this same code working with fine in another server What is the issue Please help,I could not find solution for this.

Comment: Amazon has servers in the NY area... Sandy is maybe to blame here. Lots of others hosting/service providers had issues with the power outage/flooding over there

Answer (score 4):

As a quick suggestion, check the SES time by making an HTTP request to SES (e.g. wget -S "https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"), and compare to your server's time. Update the server's time (or use NTP if you aren't already) and see if the problem resolves itself.Thanks @cyberx86.

Answer (score 1):

As experts suggested:-Britain (and probably other countries) switched over to winter time at the same day your error started happening and the error says that the time is more than 300 seconds wrong. I would vote for that being the root cause

Answer (score 0):

The one reason I can think for this is difference in the time between amazon mail server and your server.

Do the followings

1) Get the amazon mail server time

wget -S "https://email.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"

2) Get the your server time

wget -S "http://yourdomain.com"

If there is a time diffrence of more than 300 seconds, change your server time
3) sudo date *nnddhhmmyyyy.ss*
    WHERE

```
      nn- month between 01 - 12
      dd- day between 01 - 31
      hh- hour between 01 - 12
      mm- minute between 01 - 60
      yyyy - year
      ss - Seconds between 01 - 60
```